# .contents() giving error:Permission denied to access property 'nodeType' in jquery-1.8.3

Tags: jquery

I want to access iframe contents and add document object to it like

```
$(iframe).contents().add(document).on(keydown,function(){})
```

It is working fine in `jquery-1.7` but it is giving `error:Permission denied to access property 'nodeType'`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think your iframe src is from different domain. right ?

Comment: not sure why this got closed...
In short, you can’t access DOM elements within an external iFrame. You can set up something on the host server (of iFrame content) to allow access http://davidwalsh.name/iframe-permission-denied or use a proxy to load the page locally